# Trying to make a bar plot that displays total ratings by stars (1.0 , 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0) . How can I extract and group them?

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

I am attempting to make a bar plot or histogram that groups all the ratings together (i.e. groups all the 1 star ratings, 2 star ratings, etc). Id like the plot to show total ratings for each group.

```
in: df['first'] = df['rating'].str.split('out').str[0]

    rating_df = df['first'].value_counts()

    rating_df

out: 5.0     246
     4.0     169
     4.5     123
     3.5     118
     4.1     113
     3.8     111
     4.2     109
     3.7     107
     3.9     106
     4.4     105
     4.6      96
     4.3      96
     3.6      90
     4.7      84
     3.0      83
     3.3      68
     3.4      65
     3.2      59
     3.1      57
     1.0      57
     4.8      38
     2.0      31
     2.9      26
     2.6      23
     2.8      21
     2.5      17
     2.7      15
     2.3       8
     4.9       8
     2.4       7
     1.9       7

     Name: first, dtype: int64
```

Is it possible to group them all by the number of the first index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope your dataframe is as follows,

```py
     rating                counts
     5.0 Out of 5 stars    246
     4.0 Out of 5 stars    169
     4.5 Out of 5 stars    123
     ...
```

In this scenario, we can do create a new column from the rating column, then we can sum the counts by aggregation as follows.

```py
df['first'] = df['rating'].str.split('.').str[0]

df.groupby("first").agg({"counts": "sum"})
```

Comment: Got it working thank you so much! ended up using this

df['first'] = df['rating'].str.split('.').str[0]

first_df = df['first'].value_counts().sort_index()
first_df